# Bash Script to execute linux file

Tags: bash, unix

As shown in the image below, I have a Linux executable and it can be run using this command:

```
./bomb filename0.txt
```

I need a bash script to run this continuously as I have various files that I want to run the executables with as shown in the picture such as filename0, filename1, filename and so on.

[image]

How could I automate the execution of my script with all these files as argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in `seq 0 10`
do
 ./bomb filename$i.txt
done
```

The above code will run from filename0 to filename10

Comment: Thanks !! I was mixed up the syntax with python as I put filename{1}!! No wonder

Comment: This works in this precise case, but you're limited to patterns where filenames contain a number you iterate on.
I think aydow's answer is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash. This script will execute `bomb` on every file in your directory

```
for file in /path/to/dir/*.txt
do
  path/to/bomb "$file" >> results.out
done
```

Example

```
[20:37:04] ado@crystal
± >  touch a b c

[16:47:26] ado@crystal
± >  ls
a b c

[16:47:27] ado@crystal
± >  for i in *; do echo "this is $i"; done
this is a
this is b
this is c
```

Comment: Be careful, this will pass `bomb` as an argument to itself. If the argument files names are consistent, consider filtering with `*.txt` to avoid that.